# I want to integrate NFIQ sdk in my Android App

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-fingerprint-api, fingerprinting

I want to integrate following NFIQ sdk in my Android app but cannot find any solution. Any help regarding this will be appreciated:
https://github.com/usnistgov/NFIQ2
Thanks.

Comment: Do you solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately No! :(